# Write to FRAM Memory Location in MSP430

Tags: c, pointers, msp430

I am working with MSP430 with FRAM Controller. And I Have to write a data from buffer over FRAM Location.

I have gone through bundled example of writing to FRAM.

```
unsigned long *FRAM_write_ptr;
unsigned long data;
#define FRAM_TEST_START 0xD000
data = 0x00010001;
void main
{
    while(1)
    {
         data += 0x00010001;
         FRAM_write_ptr = (unsigned long *)FRAM_TEST_START;
         FRAMWrite();                            // Endless loop
         count++;
         if (count > 100)
         {
            P1OUT ^= 0x01;                        // Toggle LED to show 512K bytes
            count = 0;                            // ..have been written
            data = 0x00010001;
          }
      }
}

void FRAMWrite(void)
{
unsigned int i=0;
  for ( i= 0; i<128; i++)
  {
    *FRAM_write_ptr++ = data;
  }
}
```

But When I tested example, It goes beyond the FRAM allocated section.
Is there any other method for writing on to FRAM.?

Comment: Not clear for me. The posted code loop infinitely writing from 0xD000, but there is no limit on writing. I guess FRAM has its size, then your code is exected to check their limits.

Comment: This question was already [answered on the E2E forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/485532).

Comment: thanks @CL. for pointing it out.